# Implement multiplication by a constant with addition and bit shifts

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic, c, optimization, code-generation

While looking at the ARM instruction set, you notice that the `ADD` instruction has the so-called ["Flexible second operand"](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0068b/CIHEDHIF.html), which can be abused for quick multiplication. For example, the following instruction multiplies register `r1` by 17 (shifting it left by 4 bits and adding to itself):

```
ADD r1, r1, r1, LSL #4
; LSL means "logical shift left"
```

The subtraction instruction has that feature too. So multiplication by 15 is also easy to implement:

```
RSB r1, r1, r1, LSL #4
; RSB means "reverse subtract", i.e. subtract r1 from (r1 << 4)
```

So this is an excellent optimization opportunity! Certainly, when you write in a C program `x *= 15`, the compiler will translate that to some inefficient code, while you could replace it by `x = (x << 4) - x`, and *then* the compiler will generate better code!

Quickly, you come up with the following cunning plan:

1. Write a program or a subroutine, in any language, that receives one parameter `m`, and outputs a C optimizing macro, like the following (for `m = 15`):

   ```
   #define XYZZY15(x) (((x) << 4) - (x))
   ```

   or (which is the same)

   ```
   #define XYZZY15(x) (-(x) + ((x) << 4))
   ```
2. ???
3. Profit!

Notes:

- The macro's name is essential: magic requires it.
- [Parentheses around `x` and the whole expression are required](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10820340/509868): ancient C arcana cannot be taken lightly.
- You can assume `m` is between 2 and 65535.
- The input and output can be passed through function parameters, `stdin/stdout` or in any other customary way.
- In C, addition and subtraction have tighter precedence than bit shift `<<`; use parentheses to clarify order of calculations. More parentheses than necessary is OK.
- It is absolutely vital that the C expression be optimal, so e.g. `x+x+x` is not acceptable, because `(x<<1)+x` is better.
- Expressions `x + x` and `x << 1` are equivalent, because both require one ARM instruction to calculate. Also, `(x << 1) + (x << 2)` (multiplication by 6) requires two instructions, and cannot be improved.
- You are amazed to discover that the compiler detects that `(x << 0)` is the same as `x`, so `x + (x << 0)` is an acceptable expression. However, there is no chance the compiler does any other optimizations on your expression.
- Even though multiplication by 17 can be implemented in one instruction, multiplication by 17*17 cannot be implemented in two instructions, because there is no C expression to reflect that:

  ```
  #define XYZZY289(x) x + (x << 4) + (x + (x << 4) << 4) // 3 operations; optimal
  ```

  In other words, the compiler doesn't do common sub-expression elimination. Maybe you will fix that bug in version 2...

This is code-golf: the shortest code wins (but it must be correct, i.e. produce correct and optimal expressions for all `m`)

Please also give example outputs for `m = 2, 10, 100, 14043 and 65535` (there is no requirement on the length of the expression - it can contain extra parentheses, whitespace and shift left by 0 bits, if that makes your code simpler).

Comment: For some `2 <= m <= 65535`, there will be a worst case value where the number of bitshifts is a maximum.  Is it guaranteed that even for this worst case that it will be more efficient to do this many shifts instead of one multiplication?

Comment: Define “optimal.” I count two operations in both `x+x+x` and `(x<<1)+x`.

Comment: @FUZxxl: ARM can do as a single instruction x+(y<<k), x-(y<<k), and (y<<k)-x (for registers x,y and any constant k).  So there is only one operation in your second example.

Comment: It's not currently clear to me whether output which uses sub-macros is required or not. Please add a worked example for something like `m = 24` where that would make a difference.

Comment: Does the compiler do common subexpression elimination?  If I have `((x<<8)+1)+(((x<<8)+1)<<5)`, is that 3 ops, or 2?

Comment: @PeterTaylor, I think 24 is just `(x+(x<<1))<<3`

Comment: @KeithRandall, that's not a multiplication. Did you mean `((x<<8)+x)+(((x<<8)+x)<<5)`? That can be done in 2 steps `ADD r1, r1, r1, LSL #8` and `ADD r1, r1, r1, LSL #5`

Comment: @DigitalTrauma This is just a code-golf challenge; the explanation on performance optimization is just for fun. Compilers do this type of optimization since long ago (but don't tell anyone - it's secret!). Suppose the text starts like *You tear a leaf from the calendar - today is 8.9.89...*

Comment: @PeterTaylor Sub-macros are not required and not allowed. I added an example for 289.

Comment: @gnibbler, yes, my example should have been 27. Essentially it's the same question as Keith's.

Comment: I don't think it's right to _not_ optimise 17*17 etc. Why can't you write it in C as `x = (x << 4) + x; x = (x << 4) + x`

Comment: Can you provide a sample for m = 11?  As I understand the question, there is no possible XYZZY11 macro. I assume I'm missing something.

Comment: @gnibbler I guess your suggestion will require some sort of BFS. The rules as stated allow both BFS and bit-fiddling - more flexibility in algorithm choice is better. I agree that utilizing common sub-expressions is "more optimized", but let's leave that for version 2.0 (if at all).

Comment: @MattNoonan `#define XYZZY11(x) x + (x<<1) + (x<<3)` or `#define XYZZY11(x) -x + (x<<2) + (x<<3)` or `#define XYZZY11(x) -x + ((x + (x<<1)) << 2)` (but one should add the required additional parentheses)

Comment: @anatolyg Ah, so we can write expressions which would utilize more than one register? Great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Python - <s>414</s> <s>393</s> 331

This is my entry, which finds the least possible addition/subtraction operations, and subsequently evaluates to a C expression. Not sure it is optimal as multiplication of subexpressions may offer less operations.

```
import itertools as l
def w(N,s=''):
 for k,v in enumerate(min([t for t in l.product((1,0,-1),repeat=len(bin(N))-1)if sum([v*2**k for k,v in enumerate(t)])==N],key=lambda t:sum(abs(k)for k in t))):
  if v!=0:s+='{:+d}'.format(v)[0];s+='((x)<<{})'.format(k)if k>0 else'(x)'
 return '#define XYZZY{}(x) ({})'.format(N,s.lstrip('+'))
```

For the cases 2, 10, 100, 14043, 65535:

```
#define XYZZY2 (((x)<<1))
#define XYZZY10 (((x)<<1)+((x)<<3))
#define XYZZY100 (((x)<<2)+((x)<<5)+((x)<<6))
#define XYZZY14043 (-(x)-((x)<<2)-((x)<<5)-((x)<<8)-((x)<<11)+((x)<<14))
#define XYZZY65535(x) (-(x)+((x)<<16))
```

The final 65535 took around 11 minutes to compute. Suggestions for improvement (also speedwise) are welcome :-). Thanks to [mbomb007](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/34718/mbomb007) and [plg](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/13130/plg) for golfing improvements.

Comment: Change your 2nd line to this: `a=lambda t:sum(abs(k)for k in t)` to save some bytes. Omit any spaces you can, such as **every space before an IF**, except where the previous non-whitespace character is a letter. e.g. `'+' if` -> `'+'if` and you can do `s[0] != '+' else` -> `s[0]!='+'else`

Comment: This IS code-golf after all.

Comment: The return can be written: `return '#define XYZZY{}(x) ({})'.format(N,s.lstrip('+'))`. And `abs(v) > 0` is equivalent to `v != 0`. Calling `sorted` on `g`'s current definition can also save a char (also you should make `g` a generator -- replace the angle brackets with parentheses). Also you can define `e=enumerate`, and inline `a` into `sorted`.

Comment: Also you can apply what @mbomb007 said to `[...]0 else`: `[...]0else` is fine.

Comment: `r` is unused. `L` and `g` can be inlined. Your now inlined `g` can be written in terms of `min` instead of `sorted()[0]`. As `r` is gone, ` s=''\n` can be added as a param: `def w(N,s=''):`. After all these changes I'm down to 342, and I'm sure there are other things to do.

Comment: @plg `0else` only works with Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 508

Slightly more characters than my other answer, but this code runs in roughly one second for all cases 2, 10, 100, 14043, 65535.

```
def l(n,k=0,o=0):
 while 1:
  if k==0:
   for j in range(1,n):
    yield(j,);yield(-j,)               
   k+=1
  else:
   for j in range(1,n):
    for u in l(j,k-1,1):
     yield(j,)+u;yield(-j,)+u 
   k+=1
  if o:break 
r=lambda t:sum((1,-1)[k<0]*2**(abs(k)-1)for k in t)
def w(N,s=''):
 g = loop(len(bin(N))) 
 while 1:
  a = g.next()
  if r(a)==N:
   for k in a:
    s+='{:+d}'.format(k)[0];s+='((x)<<{})'.format(abs(k-1)) if abs(k)>1 else'(x)'
   return '#define XYZZY{}(x) ({})'.format(N,s.lstrip('+'))""")
```